# JQuery Datepicker should display date only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to display the date only without the time on the text , but it seems that it didn't work even I've set the format of the datepicker. And also I dont want to display the Time in the datepicker.
Please see image below, I want to remove the **yellow highlighted**.

```
var defaultFormat = { dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' };
$.datepicker.setDefaults(defaultFormat);
$('#EM_Date').datetimepicker({
    showHour: false,
    showMinute: false
});
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a datetimepicker when you only want the date? Why not just use a datepicker?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use $( "#EM_Date" ).datepicker();​

Answer (score 1):

use this format,

```
$('.picker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat:dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'  '', timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt', dateonly:true });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('.datePicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});
</script>
```

**Input Field**

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="datePicker" />
```

**Example** (date format *dd/mm/yy*):

[image]